# JS: Making a global function the value of an object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, return-value

Is it possible to make the return value of a (global) function the value of an object?

For example:

```
var wonka = "everlastinggobstopper";

function funky(my_string){
var string_length = my_string.length
};

myObject = {
word_length: funky(wonka),
};
```

How can I make this run without defining the function again within myObject?

Comment: Just `return string_length` from your function. What's the issue?

Comment: Just use `myObject = { word_length: funky }` might be what you mean?

Comment: I'm able to set the value equal to the function itself but not the function with "wonka" as the argument. Why can't I include arguments?

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to return something.

```
function funky(my_string) {
    var string_length = my_string.length;
    return string_length;
}
```

Your function doesn't have a `return` statement, so you're assigning `undefined` to the `word_length` property.

Comment: Thank you! That explains a lot.

What if I tried this with an array, like if var wonka = ["everlasting gobstopper", "laffy taffy", "nerds"] and then I tried to set the word_length property to funky(wonka[1])?

When I try this in a browser, I get "word_length: Array[1]" (?), but when I click on it to expand, the value of "Array[1]" is correct. Does that seem right, or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "try this in a browser" versus "click on it to expand". Can you make a jsfiddle that shows what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation! I'm really new. Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cave_coder1/8ow0n6ws/5/

Comment: When I try your fiddle the console displays `Object { word_length: 11}`

Comment: Hmm okay, must just be me. Thank you so much for all of your help!